# RTMPDUMP links in Android?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, vitamio

I have a problem here, I was trying to open an RTMP link in RtmpDump.exe and it worked successfully.

```
rtmp://www1.iguide.to/iguide<playpath>zqd4jye2ubzsk8g<swfUrl>http://www.iguide.to/player/secure_player_iguide_embed_token.swf<pageUrl>http://www.iguide.to/embedplayer_new.php?channel=31501&width=696&height=450&autoplay=true <objectEncoding>
```

But when I played the link in my Android application using both Vitamio and FFMpeg Libraries, it didn't work.

So, how can I play RTMPDUMP links in Android ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Play" as in "watch"? Try MxPlayer in the app store.

Comment: How can I play a link which contain those parameters  playpath, swfurl, Token, pageUrl in MX Player